# Rails: what will happen when you cancel(ctrl+c) long running migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have run long running migrations a few times already. Like I have some parts of the code that updates quite a lot of records and runs from several minutes to hours.

I have never tried to cancel (ctrl+c) a migration as I don't know what will happen to that migration. Would it know that the migration cancelled? What would happen to that migration and to my app? What would happen if after canceling, I run rake db:migrate again?

One of my scripts looks something like this:

```
def up
  add_column :foo, :bar, :string

  Foo.all.each do |f|
    f.bar = if f.x
      'foo'
    else
      'bar'
    end

    f.save
  end

  remove_column :foo, :something
end

def down
  * reverse of up
end
```

I'm using postgres as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the database you use. Rails uses transactions around the migrations if the database supports this for definition changes. To my knowledge PostgreSQL does this, while MySQL (at least the MyISAM tables) does not (but this may have changed).

So if you run PostgreSQL, it should cancel the transaction and that for it should be possible to simply run it again and get a clean result (though I would test this, transactions could be tricky depending on the complexity of the updating you do). MySQL would be stuck with partially updated records or maybe the version counter in the migration table wouldn't be updated and that for running it again, it would try to create the new field again and fail with an error.

Comment: Hrmn... Cause right now, I've run into this again. That script mentioned above (edited to expand update part), when I check in psql, I can see that some of my records are already updated. Would that mean that if I cancel it, it won't turn back all those records?

Comment: I have never actually tried this, so I can't say for sure. It should, if the transactions are rolled back like they should. But independent of the actual implementation I'm not sure if a ctrl-c would brake the whole thing and prevents the rollback. In this case you would have to manually rollback with some database tool. Could become tricky.

Comment: You know what actually, I think I was doing something wrong when I mentioned my "update" comment above. I did check again with the right queries and I think it didn't really run. So I did cancel, edited out update (moving it somewhere else) and run migration again, it did run this particular migration so I guess it did rollback or it didn't run a commit for that migration transaction. Thanks!